# Difference behaviour IE / Chrome for i tag

Tags: html, css

I have some difference of behaviour between Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.

I have a table with an 'i' tag. In this tag I have 2 letters: E + F

On Internet Explorer: if I hover the 'X' or the 'F' --> they are colored in blue. This is ok for me.

On Google Chrome: if I hover the 'X' --> nothing happend. (only the 'F' is ok)

How can I adjust the css to have the same behaviour as IE?

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kvehr/2/

```
<table class="search-transport">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox" value="0"/></td>   
       <td>A1</td>
       <td><i class="icon-flag-3">F</i></td>
       <td>A2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox" value="0"/></td>   
       <td>B1</td>
       <td><i class="icon-flag-3">F</i></td>
       <td>B2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

.icon-flag-3:before {
    content: "X";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is advised to use `<i>` only if it does have a semantic meaning. If just for emphisising, you should rather use `<emp>`. Won't solve your problem, though. http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/

Comment: I tried the link you provided and it works on both Chrome and IE (9).

Comment: Finally I found a solution by setting the ':hover' on the td. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kvehr/4/ Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in a comment, this seems like an IE bug.

I would suggest altering your HTML as follows:

```
[...]
<td class="has-icon-flag-3"><i class="icon-flag-3">F</i></td>
[...]
```

And your CSS:

```
.has-icon-flag-3:hover i { color: blue }
```

Also, make your CSS much less strict. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zySk4/1/).